# htaccess issue configuring pseudo style virtual host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having some issues with my htaccess file. I am trying to use rewrite rules to create a pseudo style virtual host on my apache shared hosting server.

I have 3 domains under one account and I want to achieve the following:

- If not rule exists then go to the root (domain1.co.uk)
- If domain2.co.uk set the directory to d1
- If domain3.co.uk set the directory to d2
- Irrespective of domain, if the www. is missing, add it.

The file I have at the moment is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.co.uk$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.co.uk$ [OR] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /d2/$1 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.co.uk$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain3.co.uk$ [OR] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /d3/$1
```

This originally looked like it was working except all domains seem to go into the first rule and direct to /d2. The result is that if domain1.co.uk, domain2.co.uk or domain3.co.uk is entered then they all go to domain1.co.uk.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put an [OR] on each of the second rules. It instructs Apache to look into the next rule if this one fails. When both rules fail, it then goes to the next one, which is non-existent. So your RewriteRule gets triggered in any case. That would be equivalent to doing `IF something OR somethingElse OR`, which is nonsensical.

Remove the [OR] from your second rule and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would explicitly use the first domain name in rule one and you need to tell the first rule to ignore the other 2 domains. There is also no need for `[OR]` just to check for `www`. You can make that one condition.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain(2|3)\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /d2/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain3\.co\.uk$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /d3/$1 [L]
```